# Expected identifier or keyword at the end of the expression (in get API)

Tags: angular

PLease Somebody Help.

Got Struck in calling the get API.

Getting error as unexpected token..

What the mistake have I made..

Below is my Service Method:

```
 get_tq() {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
return this.http.get(this.base_url + "learnchapter/get", { headers: headers })
  .map((res: Response) => res.json().Results||[]);
```

}

And Components.ts Method:

```
    this.service.get_tq().subscribe(data => {


  let objResponse:tResponse =data;
  if (objResponse.Code==200)
         {
          this.profile = data.Results;

  console.log(this.profile);
  this.profile.forEach((value, key) => {
    this.profileInfo.push(value);
  });   }

         else if (objResponse.Code==403)
                {

             //     $('#m1Modal').modal('hide');
                  this.toastr.error("Record already exists");

                }

});
```

And Html code:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let profiles_Result of profileInfo">

          <tr >

              <td>{{profiles_Result.}}</td>
              <td>{{profiles_Result.chaptername}}</td>
              <td>{{profiles_Result.parentflag}}</td>
              <td>{{profiles_Result.teacherflag}}</td>

                   </tr>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error - line number, code line anything?

Comment: Can you add a console log of `objResponse` inside the subscribe method. And update the question with the output?

Comment: Unexpected token , expected identifier or keyword at the end of the expression [{{profiles_Result.}}] in ng:///AppModule/LearnchapterComponent.html@264:22 ("

Comment: So - you have not written variable name after dot in this line `<td>{{profiles_Result.}}</td>`

Comment: As your question is not clear. But I am guessing that you want to access the rest API which is protected and expecting the token which you are not passing or it is getting wrong token . And @Karan Desai has mentioned very correctly that you have missed the property value but you error is telling altogether another story.